# How to think about things when it's the right time?

Tags: wandering-mind

Is there a good way to train that?

To be able to pause thinking about something that you can't change right now, until it's actually time. That might be one day, one week or one month later.

Comment: Maybe you could convince yourself that once the later time comes, you will be able to think for yourself how to do your job at that time depending on the situation and yourself at that time can do a better job without your present self telling them how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you refer to is probably 'controlling' your mind, which is a common practice called '[mindfulness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness) training', i.e., learning to observe thoughts without interacting with them.